# WPF UI not updated by INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a very simple WPF form :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"             
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="100" Name="abcdef">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=abcdef, Path=Clients}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the code behind the window :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }        
    public MainWindow()
    {            
        Clients = new List<Client>();
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 1, Name = "element 1" });
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 2, Name = "element 2" });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and the code of my class :

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { this.name = value; FirePropertyChanged("Name");}
    }        

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is working because InitializeComponent(); is after the initialisation.
However, if i put InitializeComponent() before :

```
InitializeComponent();
Clients = new List<Client>();
Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 1, Name = "element 1" });
Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 2, Name = "element 2" });
```

I should expect INotifyPropertyChanged to update my UI which is not the case.

Could you tell me what I missed ?

Updated : answer has been given using datacontext and ObservableCollection instead of List.
However it seems that the datacontext solution has solved the problem itself. I must miss something in my understanding then :

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Clients = new List<Client>();
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 1, Name = "element 1" });
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 2, Name = "element 2" });           
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 3, Name = "element 3" });
        Clients.ElementAt(0).Name = "element 1 changed";   
        Clients.RemoveAt(1);         
    }
}
```

In my case, this code updates the control and I am not using ObservableCollection. Why ?

EDIT 1
Aron gave a clear answer :
You need to understand that there are two different change notification behaviours here. The Collection changes (e.g. You add, Remove or reorder items). An Item changes (you change the Name on an element). These are handled by different processes. INotifyCollectionChanged is for the former, and INotifyPropertyChanged

And that is right because in debug mode we don't call FirePropertyChanged when callin Clients.RemoveAt(1)
However the UI is still updated with the remove... Still don't understand ;-)

EDIT 2
Now It is clear; special thanks to Amnezjak
The UI is updated because the code is used before runtime. If you add a button with a method Clients.RemoveAt(1) on click, the UI is not updated.
Now if you replace List by ObservableCollection; the button click is reflected in the UI.
Also note that you can remove all the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged  in your Client Class because ObservableCollection takes care of that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** (after question was altered)

`ObservableCollection<T>` has advantage if you want to modify collection later during application run (eg. on button click). The `List<T>` will not work in this case.

All the misunderstanding here is the difference between biding to `DataContext` and to another element (control) on the window. The first is resolved several times, also when window is showing (and then your collection is filled the way you want it to be). The latter, I believe, is resolved only during `InitializeComponent`. In that case, when you create your collection (no matter if this is `ObservableCollection<T>` or `List<T>` after `InitializeComponent`, binding gets NULL value and doesn't ask for it later.

**PREVIOUS PART**

It won't work because you are binding using `ElementName` which is indeed resolved during component initialization and is not deferred. To make it work you have to either:

1. Set `DataContext` to `this` in your window constructor and remove
   `ElementName` from your binding. This way it will work no matter
   whether you put it before or after `InitializeComponent`

   ```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Clients}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"  />

   public MainWindow()
   {            
       Clients = new List<Client>();
       Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 1, Name = "element 1" });
       Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 2, Name = "element 2" });
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;
   }
   ```
2. As others pointed out, change the collection to `ObservableCollection<T>`
   *and also* make it `DepenedencyProperty` so it can use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify window it has changed (created)
   after component initialization.

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
   {
       get { return (ObservableCollection<Client>)GetValue(ClientsProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ClientsProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ClientsProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Clients", typeof(ObservableCollection<Client>),   typeof(MainWindow));
   ```

Comment: `this.DataContext = this` is superfluous. Also I would prefer using a `readonly` backed field for the `Clients` collection, than to use a DP. As this is a more common use case.

Comment: Amnezjak, thanks. I understand better now. With List, a button calling Clients.RemoveAt(0) will not refresh UI. With ObservableCollection, it works ! an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is of course needed but not an implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Edit, actually you don't even need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your class because INotifyCollectionChanged provide this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it is because your collection doesn't support change notifications. You need a collection which supports change notifications. `ObservableCollection` does this by implementing [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface.

Use `ObservableCollection<Client>` instead of `List<Client>` that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of normal List. Your collection need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of your model class. ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all these great answers.

Amnezjak, 
as soon as I set datacontext to this, I have no problem anymore even with List instead of ObservableCollection :

```
            InitializeComponent();
        Clients = new List<Client>();
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 1, Name = "element 1" });
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 2, Name = "element 2" });
        this.DataContext = this;
        Clients.Add(new Client() { ID = 3, Name = "element 3" });
```

UI is continously updated from the model

Thus, could you explain what is the advantage to switch to ObservableCollection  in this context ?

Comment: All you've done is force a rebind. In fact, you shouldn't see element 3 with this code. Seriously...trust the other SOer, use `ObservableCollection`, it supports change notification.

Comment: But I see element 3 and you can even add Clients.ElementAt(0).Name = "element 1 changed"; and the change will reflect in UI. Be sure that I trust people answering my question because they are much more experienced. My purpose is to clearly understand the concepts.

Comment: This is so completely wrong. But I will describe what is happening. In effect what you have here is `this.DataContext = this.DataContext`. This does nothing obvious. What is DOES do is raise a `PropertyChanged` event on `DataContext`, which causes anything that is dependent on `DataContext` to rebind. Since `DataContext` is the default context (for obvious reasons) for each control, this causes EVERYTHING on your WPF control to rebind. However, if at a later stage you add more items to `Clients`, then the control would not update. It likely "worked" due to how WPF scheduled the rebinding.

Comment: By switching to an `ObservableCollection`, every `.Add` will cause a `CollectionChanged` event to be raised. Your `ListBox` will have subscribed to that event, and will add a new `ListBoxItem` (and not rebind) for the new `Client`. Since it didn't rebind, the old `ListBoxItem`s are still there, preserving the state of them (as well as the UI state of the rest of your Control).

Comment: Please in future edit your question instead of asking a question in an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aron for your clear explanation. I will try to understand why my control are updated even with a List. In debug mode, FirePropertyChanged is called each time the List is updated; this may be the explanation.

Comment: You need to understand that there are two different change notification behaviours here. The Collection changes (e.g. You add, Remove or reorder items). An Item changes (you change the `Name` on an element). These are handled by different processes. `INotifyCollectionChanged` is for the former, and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for the latter.

Comment: @Aron other SOers solutions will not work because binding is resolved during component initialization and in this case the collection is NULL. The `ObservableCollection` property must implement also `INotifyPropertyChaged` interface to inform framework it has changed (created) after `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: As asked by Aron, I have edited the original question according to our discussion.